# Uno for Xamarin forms running "dotnet new wasmxfhead" does not create a wasm project but converts all the existing projects to uno templates

Tags: xamarin.forms, uno-platform

I am trying to use the uno platform for Xamarin forms to bring xamarin forms app to the web. But while running the dotnet new wasmxfhead command does not create a wasm project but converts all the existing projects to uno template. Anyone know how to solve this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command seems to have regressed in Uno 2.2.0, but you can work around this by using the 2.1 version of the templates:

```
dotnet new -i Uno.ProjectTemplates.Dotnet::2.1
```

Then in your Xamarin.Forms projects that contains a UWP head, you can run:

```
dotnet new wasmxfhead
```